# updating multiple value of one column of table in  zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

i have an an array

```
$array_to_pass; //this array is created dynamically looks like this

Array
(
 [cal] => 1
 [sms] => 1
 [contacts] => 0
 [browsing] => 1
 [history] => 0
 [photo] => 0
 )
```

now i want to update  table with name "my_table".in my_table there are column with name "flags" and "value_of_flags "**under column 'flags' there are many flags** but i want to  **UPDATE**  Only these.i mean cal,sms,contacts,browsing,history,photo
 in the above array lets say `[cal] => 1`  so 'cal' is the name of the flag and i want to set value of 1  or 0 to 'value_of_flags' column,
the WHERE CLAUSE ll be "where id = $var"
how would i write this query ???

my table looks like this

```
  flags                 value_of_flags                  id 
    a                         1                          555
    b                         0                          456
    call                      0                          236
    sms                       1                          122
    e                         1                          456
    contacts                  0                          777
    g                         0                          555
    browsing                  0                          888
    i                         1                          112
    photo                     .                           .
    .                         .                           .
    .                         .                           .
```

**EDITED**

```
function Save_User_Prefrences($array_to_pass,$phone_service_id){
    $DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

    //$whereStr = "phone_service_id = " . (int)$phone_service_id;
      foreach ($array_to_pass as $key => $value) {
         $DB->update('user_preferences',
         array(
             $key => $value
             ),
          "phone_service_id = " . $phone_service_id
); }
```

**error**

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:    Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'call' in 'field list in pdo.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$idWhereStr = "phone_service_id = " . (int)$phone_service_id;
foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
    $DB->update(
        'user_preferences',
        array(
            'value_of_flags' => $value
        ),
        $DB->quoteInto("flags = ?", $key) . " AND " . $idWhereStr
    );
}
```

Comment: thanQ very much sir but  why this $whereStr = "id = " . (int)$id;
??

Comment: `$whereStr` is your `WHERE` clause. You want to `UPDATE` only the row with `id=555`. `$myDbTable` is the instance of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` with `$_name = "my_table"`

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cal' in 'field list'' in D:

Comment: sir kindly see the edited portion what actually i am trying to do

Comment: actually i am updating call,sms,contacts,photo in a column name =flags and value_of_flags  in a  table = user_preferences

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'call' in 'where clause

Comment: thanQ very much sir so nice of you

Answer (score -1):

```
$whereStr = "id = " . (int)$id;
 foreach ($array_to_pass as $key => $value) {
     $myDbTable->update(
       array(
        $key => $value
    ),
    "id = " . $whereStr
  );
}
```